# Can you translate this scroll painting. Signature & words. Thank you

Tags: character-identification

This is a scroll painting of a Rooster.  Could you help identify who painted Era and what description.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't do seals at all, but the black writing looks like:

Right hand column:

二四年
èrsì nián
（19）24 year

大暑悲鸿
dàshǔ bēihóng
big heat Beihong

大暑 is a time in the Chinese solar calendar: 23rd July-6th August

There was a famous artist and art teacher: 徐悲鸿 Xú Bēihóng 1895—1953 (Trained in Europe I read.)

Comment: It should be (民國)二**十**四年(1935). 1924 = 一九二四.

Comment: the seal is “悲鴻㞢印”. well, “大暑” is the 12th solar terms; most would treat it as a day, not a period. that, in the year of 1935, 大暑 is on 24th july  https://www.hko.gov.hk/tc/gts/time/calendar/pdf/files/1935.pdf

Comment: I learned something! Thank you! A quote from Douglas Adams: Time is an illusion, lunchtime doubly so!

Comment: :) FYI. It is not rare to see these Chinese number characters:  十(10), 廿(20), 卅(30), and the rarity - 卌(40). The twenty written in the test is the simplified 廿. https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/623703784028412684.html